# unable to load node_modules files for angular2 in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, angular

I am developing a app in nodejs with angular2. in which i have link the node_modules file in my index.html page. but when i load my app it unable to load the angular2 file form moude_modules flolder:

here is my **server.js** config for static content which in **app** folder

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

here is my **index.html** link

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

here is my folder structure :

```
-app
|-server.js
-node_modules
-public
|-index.html
```

its giving me error:

[image]

please correct me to serve those file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setting multi folder express_static

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules')));
```

inside index.html

```
<script src="/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: please ans my other que http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703574/unable-to-load-bootstrap-file-in-angular2-nodejs-app